# The running in GCE crashed at some fixed point

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

[The code always stops at 60%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrzWb.png)

Everytime I run this pre-processing code, it will stuck at 60%. Then, I cannot open another session when I click the "ssh" near the instance in the window only if I cancel the session for this crashed running code.

Also, if I use local ubuntu to connect this remote GCE, it will also stuck at 60% and when I open another terminal to conncect the GCE, it will show "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer".

Hope someone can help me, I would really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The configuration of my GCE is 8vCPU with 60GB RAM and one NVIDIA Tesla P100.

Comment: This issue seems to be caused due to  some resource or memory exhaustion in your instance. 
Can you share the output of top command?

Comment: @PatrickW Thank you! I solved this problem, it is the out of memory that causes this problem! Thank you so much.